# how to avoid name conflicts coming from #define in C? (or C++)

Tags: c++, c, scope, preprocessor

This should be very basic question, and I can avoid this situation by changing some names but I think maybe there is something I am missing here.
I have made a simplest code for this problem.

```
conv.h :
  1 struct convpar_ {
  2 int K;
  3 } convpar_;

test.c :
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include "conv.h"
  3 
  4 #define K 7
  5 
  6 typedef struct convpar_ convpar;
  7 
  8 void func1(convpar cp)
  9 {
 10 printf("cp.K = %d\n", cp.K);
 11 }
 12 
 13 main()
 14 {
 15 convpar cp = {K};
 16 
 17 func1(cp);
 18 }
```

If I do `cc test.c -o test`, I get

```
cc     test.c   -o test
test.c: In function 'func1':
test.c:13: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
```

I know this is because I defined character 'K' as '7' in line 4 and this makes line 10 appear `printf("cp.7" = %d\n", cp.7);` after preprocessing. When I change the name of convpar_'s member K to something else(ex. Ki), this problem goes away.

But at times, there are cases like it here when I want to define a constant and it happens to be a name of a global variable or a member variable of a struct I use in the same file I defined the variable in. What is the right approach to solve this problem? (this also applies to C++)

Comment: In `C++` you can use namespaces. In `C` and `C++`, you can rename.

Comment: Don't use macros (`#define`). If you want a constant, use a `const` (or `constexpr`) variable (in a namespace).

Comment: use `#if defind xxx ` statement.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I can use define macro to define another macro. But with const type, cannot. I can use the const type inside a function to define a variable. What if I want to declare a static array and I want to define the size of the array using some operation on the define macro? Maybe I'll put a new question..

Comment: The correct syntax for initializing a struct member is `convpar cp = { .K = K};` But this will also end up with similar compilation error.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Hi, I would appreciate if you could give me an advice or answer to my new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884007/in-c-how-to-define-a-macro-using-other-macros-when-that-other-macros-raise-nam

Comment: @nguaial that only works for C or C++20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot work around this because that's the preprocessor goal: modifying your code on the fly. The solution is to adopt good coding practices: don't use the preprocessor for general programming. Also, use a naming discipline with namespaces. K what ? Name it CONVERSION_ID_K, CONVERSION_ID_L, and so on. Use lower case for variables, etc.

Comment: ok, maybe that's the general answer. Also I found Jeper Juhl's comment (using const int rather than #define) useful.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could give me an answer/comment on my new question :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884007/in-c-how-to-define-a-macro-using-other-macros-when-that-other-macros-raise-nam

Answer (score 0):

The answer to "How to avoid naming conflicts" is generally: use proper names (and not `K`). Additionally, for C++, [use namespaces](https://abseil.io/tips/130) and [**don't** use using-directives i.e. `using namespace`](https://abseil.io/tips/153).

So the code could become something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace MyNamespaceName {
    struct MyStructName {
        int myVariableName;
    };

    // probably even a member function, and struct->class, and member variable private
    void MyFunctionName(MyStructName const& myStructInstanceName) {
        std::cout << "clearStructInstanceName.clearVariableName = "
            << myStructInstanceName.myVariableName
            << '\n';
    }

    static constexpr auto myStaticVariableName = 7;
}

int main() {
    auto const myStructInstanceName =
        ::MyNamespaceName::MyStructName {
            ::MyNamespaceName::myStaticVariableName
        };

    ::MyNamespaceName::MyFunctionName(myStructInstanceName);
}
```

This is probably overkill for most situations, but when working on big collaborative projects, you really need you keep the global namespace clean and consider that there will be others that think of the same variable names as you.