# How to define a macro using other macros, when those other macros raise name conflicts

Tags: c, scope, macros

This is a follow-up question to this (please read my question to the end) :
[how to avoid name conflicts coming from #define in C? (or C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43883432/how-to-avoid-name-conflicts-coming-from-define-in-c-or-c)
Suppose that I #define macros ROW and COL. I then #define ARRSIZE using ROW and COL. Then, I declare a static array like `float myarray[ARRSIZE];`. Now if I modify ROW and COL, the static array size changes accordingly. But in my special case, the names of ROW and COL conflict with a member name of a struct type I'm using in the same file. Someone told me to use a const variable instead of using '#define' to avoid the conflict. I liked the idea and modifed the code as shown below (it's an example).

```
const int ROW = 100;
const int COL = 200;
const int ARRSIZE = ROW*COL;
float myarray[ARRSIZE];
```

Compling this gives me

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'ARRSIZE'
```

at the line where I define ARRSIZE. Of course I can use `int ARRSIZE = ROW*COL;` inside a function and dynamically allocate the array inside the function with malloc. But what if I want to change only ROW and COL and don't want to use malloc?  Of course, there is no problem (except the name conflicts) when doing it with #define.

```
#define ROW 100
#define COL 200
#define ARRSIZE ROW*COL
float myarray[ARRSIZE];
```

So the problem: I want to change only ROW, COL and want the static array size automatically changed, but at the same time, ROW and COL appear as a member variable of a struct in the same source file. I cannot fix the name of the struct member. So in a word, I want to define a 'macro like values' that are not applied to a member function/variable nor global variables. What is the best practice to do it in my case? Just changing the variables ROW and COL to something special? Having asked this question, I get an impression that, that may be the only solution.. :)

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: This is C. (but could apply to C++, even inside the same namespace?)

Comment: `const` creates read-only variables in C, not constants. C++ is different.

Comment: If you cannot change the "ROW" and "COL" in the header, why don't use slgihtly different names in your code? Is there also a name conflict with "ARRAY" somewhere?

Comment: @melpomene Please explain the difference between a read-only variable and a constant.

Comment: I can change my local ROW, COL to something else, but I'm curious if I can do it with the same names. looks like changing the names is the corret answer..?

Comment: @Yunnosch Constants can be used e.g. as case labels or array dimensions; variables can't (unless your compiler supports VLAs, then you can use them for arrays).

Comment: It is, if it solves your problem.

Comment: @melpomene I know const is a read-only variables( I cannot change it later), and constant is like '3.141592' or '300'.

Comment: `enum { ROW = 100 }; enum { COL = 200 }; enum { ARRSIZE = ROW*COL };`

Comment: @melpomene Thanks. I think I would specify/descibre that kind of constant as "compile time static value" (maybe "link time") . But I see your point.

Comment: @melpomene Wow, that seems to solve my case. please make it a short answer, I'll select it as the answer.

Comment: That looks like (the very nice) half of an answer, the other half being the use of non-conflicting names. To be chosen from according to usecase.

Comment: A bit late but try removing the leading \ before ROW in your original example

Comment: @melpomene: "Read-only variable" sounds like an oxymoron. C is such an irritating language!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling comments to make an answer:

Solution A,
if you for some reason have to stick with "ROW" and "COL" in your code (credits to melpomene):

```
enum { ROW = 100 }; 
enum { COL = 200 }; 
enum { ARRSIZE = ROW*COL };
```

Solution B,
if you are free to choose identifiers; more robust for future reuse:
Avoid the naming conflict by choosing different, non-conflicting, longer identfiers.
I have a superstitious distrust of short, obvious identifiers, the conflict you encountered is a good example why. Other examples have cost my employers quite some time and money.

*(I have seen melpomene elsewhere not being interested in the reputation for an answer anymore, very altruistical. I think it is worth making a nice Q/A pair here and does not take anything from melpomene.)*

Comment: Thanks for the perfece answer.

Comment: @melpomene Seems that junior-partnering with you is lucky. And thanks for confirming that you do not mind.